# Как в автосвойствах(сокращённых свойствах) сделать проверку на ввод?

Tags: c#

В данном примере обычное свойство, и проблем с проверкой нет.

```
private string test;

public string Test
{
get
 {
    return test;
 } 
set
{
     //проверка
   name = value;
} 

}
```

А  без поля что возвращать get? У нас же нет поля, оно подразумевается в свойстве
public int perem{get;set;}
В set то value есть, а в get куда.
Вообщем как сделать проверку в сокращённо свойстве или её нельзя там сделать, оно на то и сокращённое, что экономит код?

```
public string Test
{
get
 {
    return ;что мне тут возвратить? Если нет поля? 
 } 
set
{
     //проверка
   name = value;
} 

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В автосвойствах делать проверку нельзя. Только в простых свойствах. Значит, нужно вручную добавлять поле:

```
string _test; // это поле
public string Test {
  get { return _test; } 
  set {
    bool proverka = ...; // проверка
    if (proverka) _test = value;
  }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, а то запутался, с set проблем не было, а вот get нечего возвращать было. ❤️